# Cannot access to addon preference value

Tags: add-on, customization

I have something like this in the my add-on `__init__` file:

```
class MyPreferences(AddonPreferences):
    
    bl_idname = __name__

    num: IntProperty(name="Number", default=888)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "num")
```

I need to get this number from another file, and "MyPreferences.num" doesn't work. It returns a tuple, where the first value is "<built-in function IntProperty>" and the second value is a dictionary.

I can access the dictionary values, but the only ones available are "name", "attr", and "default", so if the user changes the property, I can't access the new value.

What should I do?

Comment: Would help if this example was self contained

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this

```
addon = bpy.context.preferences.addons.get(addon_name)
if addon:
    prefs = addon.preferences
    print(prefs.num)
```