# Python: access addon preferences default value

Tags: python, scripting

How to access the default value in addon preferences

```
class TEST(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __package__

    test_int: bpy.props.IntProperty(name = "", default = 9)

bpy.context.preferences.addons[__package__].preferences.test_int = 0

# given a string to get property default value
def return_default_value(name):
    P = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__package__].preferences
    output = P.bl_rna.properties['test_int'].default
    return output

if return_default_value("test_int") == 9:
   print("success!")
```

Comment: In which case this should answer the question https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31041/86891

Comment: The edited version of the question makes it perfectly clear that the proposed duplicate does not answer the question.